# mysql fetch() return null values

Tags: php

I'm really new to php, I wanted to get data that has been stored before using fetch(). It return the exact number of rows in the database, but with null values.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'DbOperation.php';

$db = new DbOperation(); 

$devices = $db->getAllDevices();

$response = array(); 

$response['error'] = false; 
$response['antrian_mobile'] = array(); 

while($device = $devices->fetch()){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['id']=$device['id'];
    $temp['email']=$device['email'];
    $temp['token']=$device['token'];
    array_push($response['antrian_mobile'],$temp);
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

the function of getAllDevices:

```
public function getAllDevices(){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare(" SELECT email, token FROM antrian_mobile ");
    //$stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
    $stmt->bind_result($email,$token);
    $stmt->execute();
    //$stmt->store_result();
    //$result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $stmt; 
}
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Because you're only selecting email and token

Comment: yes I only want to get the email and token, the result is id,email and token is null.

Comment: please `var_dump($devices->fetch())` and post the result

Comment: `bind_result()` says where to store the results, yet your trying to get the values from the return from `fetch()`

Comment: var_dump return me internal error, sorry if I'm so stupid I'm not used to code

Comment: just change `return $stmt` to `return $stmt->fetch();` Change your while to `while($device)` and iterate over it.

Comment: it return another error Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted I dont understand, my database only stored 8 rows of data

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think you had return wrong value into getAllDevices function.

remove the comment from this "$result = $stmt->get_result()".

and return the $result variable instead of $stmt.

try this

Comment: I can't use the get_result because I'm using mysqli not mysqlnd, that's why I change it to bind_result